# Google Play Service v 6.5 to v 7.0.0 differences

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

Has anyone gone through the Google-Play-Services API documentation and worked out what's changed syntactically between v6.5 and 7.0.0?

Looking for a crib sheet to save me having to compile my own eg.

v <7 Syntax:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.API)

....

// Begin by creating the query.
DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();
DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

....

Status insertStatus = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                        .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Becomes in v >= 7.0.0:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)

 ....

// Begin by creating the query.
DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();
PendingResult<DataReadResult> pendingResult = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(
                mClient,
                readRequest);
DataReadResult readDataResult = pendingResult.await();

....

PendingResult<Status> pendingStatus = Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet);
Status insertStatus = pendingStatus.await();
```

I am also wondering if the **GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) ... if (!authInProgress)** example block, on the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) page, should also capture **ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED** results?

I ask as since moving to the latest version I've notice the occasional:

```
 google fit Connection failed. Cause: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,
```

error, so wondering rather than the suggested:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)

....

    if (!authInProgress) {
            if (result.getErrorCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.NEEDS_OAUTH_PERMISSIONS) {
```

we / the site should use:

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)

....

    if (!authInProgress) {
            if (result.getErrorCode() == FitnessStatusCodes.NEEDS_OAUTH_PERMISSIONS
                   || result.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED
             ) {
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156832/fitness-api-removed-in-google-play-services-7-0?rq=1

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154332/android-google-fit-onconnectionfailed-sign-in-required